# PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores not returning anything

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

In my game I am using the Google Play Games Services to implement online leaderboards for players to use where they can submit their player scores after finishing a level.
When I test the game on my phone and at the end of a level submit my score to the leaderboard, the callback is returning as successful, but this is where my issue appears.

When I use the default google UI to look at the leaderboards

```
    public void ShowDefaultLeaderboard()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI();
    }
```

the scores do indeed appear, as shown in the UI images:
[downtownleaderboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJxx1.png)
[forestleaderboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3eD7.png)

and also showing up in my logcat as such:
[reportscorelogcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSrpx.png)

But when I tap on my name in the leaderboards, this also appears:
[Nointernetconnection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCjCo.jpg)

My main problem is that when I try to open my custom UI and use the PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores() method to retrieve leaderboard data to put into my own UI, it is giving me this error in my logcat:
[loadscoresfailederror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69z5P.png)

And when I look in the leaderboard section of my Google Play Games console, there are no entries, only dashes that appear.
[consoleleaderboards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvkzF.png)

This is my LeaderboardManager script that i've made and i've had several people look over it and confirm that everything looks good and should be working, so I feel it's more of a problem outside of my script and rather an issue with my script, but in case anyone wants to have a look at it as well, here it is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class LeaderboardManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static LeaderboardManager Instance;

    private string leaderboardID = "level1leaderboardID";
    private LeaderboardStart leaderboardStart = LeaderboardStart.TopScores;
    private int scoresToDisplay = 100;
    private LeaderboardCollection leaderboardType = LeaderboardCollection.Public;
    private LeaderboardTimeSpan leaderboardTimeSpan = LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime;

    [SerializeField] private LeaderboardEntryCard template;
    [SerializeField] private Transform container;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject uploadResult;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject uploadButton;
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Dropdown dropMenu;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void ShowDefaultLeaderboard()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI();
    }

    public void RefreshLeaderboard()
    {
        LoadLeaderboard();
    }

    private void LoadLeaderboard()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(leaderboardID,
            leaderboardStart,
            scoresToDisplay,
            leaderboardType,
            leaderboardTimeSpan,
            (LeaderboardScoreData data) => {

                //Making list of userIDs
                List<string> userIDs = new List<string>();

                //Mapping userIDs to scores
                Dictionary<string, IScore> userScores = new Dictionary<string, IScore>();
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Scores.Length; i++)
                {
                    IScore score = data.Scores[i];
                    userIDs.Add(score.userID);
                    userScores[score.userID] = score;
                }

                //Mapping userIDs to usernames
                Dictionary<string, string> userNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                Social.LoadUsers(userIDs.ToArray(), (users) =>
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
                    {
                        userNames[users[i].id] = users[i].userName;

                        Debug.Log($"User {users[i].id}: {users[i].userName}");
                    }

                    //Looping through the data so that scores and users align correctly, then instantiating the entry cards
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.Scores.Length; i++)
                    {
                        IScore score = data.Scores[i];

                        string userName = userNames[score.userID];

                        int rank = score.rank;

                        var card = Instantiate(template, container);
                        card.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                        card.SetEntry(rank, userName, score.value);
                    }

                });

            });
    }

    private string GetLeaderboardCode()
    {
        int currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

        if (currentScene == 2)
        {
            return "level1leaderboardID";
        }
        else if(currentScene == 3)
        {
            return "level2leaderboardID";
        }
        else if(currentScene == 4)
        {
            return "level3leaderboardID";
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public void PostScoreToLeaderboard()
    {
        long leaderboardScore = long.Parse(GameManager.Instance.highscoreText.text);
        Social.ReportScore(leaderboardScore, GetLeaderboardCode(), (bool success) =>
        {
            if (success)
            {
                uploadButton.SetActive(false);
                StartCoroutine(UploadResult("Successfully uploaded!"));
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine(UploadResult("Failed to upload score."));
            }
        });
    }

    private IEnumerator UploadResult(string result)
    {
        uploadResult.SetActive(true);
        uploadResult.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = $"{result}";
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2f);
        uploadResult.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void SetLeaderboard()
    {
        int selectedOption = dropMenu.value;

        switch (selectedOption)
        {
            case 0:
                leaderboardID = "level1leaderboardID";
                break;
            case 1:
                leaderboardID = "level2leaderboardID";
                break;
            case 2:
                leaderboardID = "level3leaderboardID";
                break;
        }
        LoadLeaderboard();
    }
}
```

I've also checked that both of my SHA-1 keys are matched up correctly in my Google Cloud Platform and in the configuration section of my Play Games Services and they do match. Everything is also published on both the cloud platform and play console side in terms of OAuth consent screen, OAuth2.0 credentials and PGS credentials are published.

I'm kind of stuck on what to do at this point, so any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.
I'm currently testing my game by uploading to a closed testing track for new features in the console.
I've also tried simply building and running to my phone straight from the Unity editor.